# Highlight the cells on the left lower half of the table(triangle)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have an html table that is created dynamically based on provided number of rows & columns.
I have successfully created the table now i want to highlight the cells on the left lower half of the table(triangle) with light red color. Same as in the attached file https://www.screencast.com/t/Va4Xz4v4

The code i used for creating the table

```js
//Event handler function
function print_table() {
  let _tblRows, _tblCols, tblElm, rowElm, colElm, randNmbrArray, _tblDiv, _randNmbrAvg, avgElm;

  _tblRows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
  _tblCols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
  randNmbrArray = [];
  _tblDiv = document.getElementById('my_table')
  avgElm = document.getElementById('average');

  if (_tblRows == "") {
    alert("Please enter rows!");
  } else if (_tblCols == "") {
    alert("Please enter columns!");
  } else {
    tblElm = document.createElement('table');

    for (var i = 0; i < _tblRows; i++) {
      rowElm = document.createElement('tr');
      for (var j = 0; j < _tblCols; j++) {
        let _randNmbr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        randNmbrArray.push(_randNmbr);
        colElm = document.createElement('td');
        colElm.appendChild(document.createTextNode(_randNmbr));
        rowElm.appendChild(colElm);

      }
      tblElm.appendChild(rowElm);
    }
    _tblDiv.innerHTML = "";
    _tblDiv.append(tblElm);

    _randNmbrAvg = GetAverage(randNmbrArray);
    avgElm.innerHTML = "";
    avgElm.append(`The average of the number in the table is ${_randNmbrAvg.toFixed(2)}`);

  }
}

function GetAverage(numberArray) {
  let total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
    total += numberArray[i];
  }
  return total / numberArray.length;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: auto 25px auto 25px;
}

table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid #70AEC5;
}

td {
  padding: 3px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #70AEC5;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 0;
}

tr:hover {
  background: #ddd
}

h1 {
  color: #70AEC5;
}

#directions {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #70AEC5;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 25px 15px 25px;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.triangle {
  background-color: #ffcccc;
}
```

```html
<h1>Generating a Table</h1>
<h4>By Yukong Zhang</h4>
Rows: <input id="rows" type="text" size="3" value="15"> Columns: <input id="cols" type="text" size="3" value="15">
<button id="print" type="button" onclick="print_table()">Generate</button><br>
<div id="my_table"></div>
<h4 id="average"></h4>
```

Now i only wants to highlight the lower half side of the table(triangle).

Comment: How accurate is the screenshot you provided?

Comment: Screenshot is actually the result i want to be done, everything is complete except the colouring part

Comment: Well I just tried a solution to this that I have used before and it didn't yield the same result (some cells don't match). I think my solution is valid. Would you be interested to see it?

Comment: Yes definitely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have to compare the `x` and `y` coordinates of the cell. For a square matrix, the lower left triangle of cells matches the condition `x <= y`, the top left matches `y <= numberOfColumns - x`, and so on ...

So to highlight the lower left cells just add the `triangle` class to every cell that passes the condition `j <= i` (`i` is the index of the current row and `j` is the index of the current column).

Since the generated matrix is not always a square one (the number of columns is different than the number of rows), we have to normalize the `x` and `y` coordinates, to do so we just divide the `x` coordinate by the number of columns and the `y` coordinate by the number of rows (that way both normalized coordinates can go from `0` to `1`). So we highlight the cells that match the condition `j / (_tblCols - 1) <= i / (_tblRows - 1)` (subtracting 1 from both number of columns and rows to account for the fact that the indexes `i` and `j` start at `0`).

Inside the inner loop add:

```
if(j / (_tblCols - 1) <= i / (_tblRows - 1)) {
    colElm.className = "triangle";
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
//Event handler function
function print_table() {
  let _tblRows, _tblCols, tblElm, rowElm, colElm, randNmbrArray, _tblDiv, _randNmbrAvg, avgElm;

  _tblRows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
  _tblCols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
  randNmbrArray = [];
  _tblDiv = document.getElementById('my_table')
  avgElm = document.getElementById('average');

  if (_tblRows == "") {
    alert("Please enter rows!");
  } else if (_tblCols == "") {
    alert("Please enter columns!");
  } else {
    tblElm = document.createElement('table');

    for (var i = 0; i < _tblRows; i++) {
      rowElm = document.createElement('tr');
      for (var j = 0; j < _tblCols; j++) {
        let _randNmbr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        randNmbrArray.push(_randNmbr);
        colElm = document.createElement('td');
        colElm.appendChild(document.createTextNode(_randNmbr));
        rowElm.appendChild(colElm);

        if(j / (_tblCols - 1) <= i / (_tblRows - 1)) {
          colElm.className = "triangle";
        }
      }
      tblElm.appendChild(rowElm);
    }
    _tblDiv.innerHTML = "";
    _tblDiv.append(tblElm);

    _randNmbrAvg = GetAverage(randNmbrArray);
    avgElm.innerHTML = "";
    avgElm.append(`The average of the number in the table is ${_randNmbrAvg.toFixed(2)}`);

  }
}

function GetAverage(numberArray) {
  let total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
    total += numberArray[i];
  }
  return total / numberArray.length;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: auto 25px auto 25px;
}

table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid #70AEC5;
}

td {
  padding: 3px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #70AEC5;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 0;
}

tr:hover {
  background: #ddd
}

h1 {
  color: #70AEC5;
}

#directions {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #70AEC5;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 25px 15px 25px;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.triangle {
  background-color: #ffcccc;
}
```

```html
<h1>Generating a Table</h1>
<h4>By Yukong Zhang</h4>
Rows: <input id="rows" type="text" size="3" value="15"> Columns: <input id="cols" type="text" size="3" value="15">
<button id="print" type="button" onclick="print_table()">Generate</button><br>
<div id="my_table"></div>
<h4 id="average"></h4>
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I’m looking for!

Comment: @Saif Great! BTW please verify that you're using the correct code (I updated my answer after I realized that I had made a mistake).

Answer (score 2):

My solution uses the slope of the line that would bisect the two halves of the chart and then increments the count of cells to color by this slope.

`var slope = _tblCols/_tblRows`

Demo:

```js
//Event handler function
function print_table() {

    let _tblRows, _tblCols, tblElm, rowElm, colElm,randNmbrArray,_tblDiv,_randNmbrAvg,avgElm;

    _tblRows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
    _tblCols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
    randNmbrArray = [];
    _tblDiv = document.getElementById('my_table')
    avgElm = document.getElementById('average');

    if (_tblRows == "") {
        alert("Please enter rows!");
    } 
    else if(_tblCols == ""){
        alert("Please enter columns!");
    }
    else {
        tblElm = document.createElement('table');
        var coloredCells = 1
        var slope = _tblCols/_tblRows //Get the slope
        for (var i = 0; i < _tblRows; i++) {
    
          
            rowElm = document.createElement('tr');
            for (var j = 0; j < _tblCols; j++) {
                let _randNmbr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
                randNmbrArray.push(_randNmbr);
                colElm = document.createElement('td');
              if(j < coloredCells){
                colElm.classList.add("triangle")
              }
                colElm.appendChild(document.createTextNode(_randNmbr));
                rowElm.appendChild(colElm);

            }
            coloredCells+= slope; //Increment by the slope
            tblElm.appendChild(rowElm);
          
        }
        _tblDiv.innerHTML="";
        _tblDiv.append(tblElm);

        _randNmbrAvg = GetAverage(randNmbrArray);
        avgElm.innerHTML = "";
        avgElm.append(`The average of the number in the table is ${_randNmbrAvg.toFixed(2)}`);

    }
}

function GetAverage(numberArray){
let total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
    total += numberArray[i];
}
return total / numberArray.length;
}
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: auto 25px auto 25px;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid #70AEC5;
}
td
{
    padding: 3px;
}

th {
     border: 1px solid white;
     background-color: #70AEC5;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 4px 0 4px 0;
 }

tr:hover{background: #ddd}

h1{
    color: #70AEC5;
}

#directions {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #70AEC5;
    padding: 10px; 
    margin: 10px 25px 15px 25px;
}

button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.triangle
{
   background-color:#ffcccc;
}
```

```html
<h1>Generating a Table</h1>
<h4>By Yukong Zhang</h4>
Rows: <input id="rows" type="text" size="3" value="15">
Columns: <input id="cols" type="text" size="3" value="15">
<button id="print" type="button" onclick="print_table()">Generate</button><br>
<div id="my_table"></div>
<h4 id="average"></h4>
```

Comment: It works only when the number of rows & columns are same if you change the columns to 25 then it is not producing the same result as in the attached link https://www.screencast.com/t/Va4Xz4v4

Comment: @Saif I've updated the answer to take that into account